# contractive and find its limit

Tags: calculus, limits, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

The real sequence $\{P_n\}$ is defined as $p_1$=2, $p_{n+1}$=$\frac{2}{1+p_n}$, n $\in N$. prove that $\{p_n\}$ is contractive, deduce that it converges, and find its limit.
first we need to show that $\frac{2}{3}$ $\leq$ $p_n$$\leq$2

pf:
as $p_1$ = 2, $p_2$=$\frac{2}{3}$,.. so that  $\frac{2}{3}$ $\leq$ 1 $\leq$2

now we have $\vert \frac{2}{1+p_{n+1}} - \frac{2}{1+p_n} \vert$ =...some crazy math here..=

since $p_1$=2 and $p_n\lt$1, for all$ $ $n\geq2$ by induction we have 2$\frac{\vert p_n - p_{n+1}\vert}{(1+p_n)(1+p_{n+1})}$ $\lt$ $\frac{2}{2}$* $\frac{2}{2}$ $\vert p_n - p_{n+1} \vert$ = $\vert p_n - p_{n+1} \vert$ therefore $p_n$ is a contractive sequence.

is that good or need to fix my $\lt$ $\frac{2}{2}$* $\frac{2}{2}$

Comment: What do you mean *a sequence* is "contractive"?

Comment: contractive sequences: a real sequence $\{p_n\}$ is said to be a contractive sequence if there exists $b \in R$ with $0<b<1$ s.t. $\vert p_{n+1}-p_n \vert$ $\lt$ b$\vert p_n - p_{n-1} \vert$ for all n $\in$ N, n $\gt$ 2

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close. *If we can show* that $p_k\ge \frac{2}{3}$ for all $k$, we will have, by a calculation similar to yours, that
$$|p_{n+1}-p_n|=\left|\frac{2}{1+p_n}-\frac{2}{1+p_{n-1}}\right|=\frac{2|p_n-p_{n-1}|}{(1+p_n)(1+p_{n-1})}.$$
But since $p_k\ge \frac{2}{3}$ for all $k$, it follows that $(1+p_k)(1+p_{n-1})\ge \frac{25}{9}$. This implies that
$$|p_{n+1}-p_n|\le \frac{18}{25}|p_n-p_{n-1}|,$$
which proves contractivenes.

---

To show that $p_k\ge \frac{2}{3}$ for all $k$, we show the stronger  result $\frac{2}{3}\le p_k\le 2$. This is done by induction.

Suppose that $p_k\le 2$. We show that $p_{k+1}\ge \frac{2}{3}$. This is obvious.

Suppose that $\frac{2}{3}\le p_k$. Then $p_{k+1}\le \frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{6}{5}\le 2$.

This completes the induction step.

Comment: how would you find the limit? by using quadratic formula?

Comment: Sort of. I have given a more or less complete solution that incorporates elements of yours. Note that is is **not enough** to prove that $|p_{n+1}-p_n|\lt |p_n-p_{n-1}|$. For contractiveness we must get a constant **less than** $1$ in there. That's my $\frac{18}{25}$. You will also have to find the limit $p$. That's easy, solve $p=\frac{2}{1+p}$.

Comment: cool got the limit part, but still try to get the less then 1 in there.

Comment: There was perhaps a misunderstanding of contractiveness embedded in what you wrote. We need a constant less than $1$ to force convergence. Mere less than is not enough, one can construct examples where we have $\lt$ but not convergence.

Comment: can i use your $\frac{18}{25}$. all i need is make b to be less then one

Comment: We needed a constant less than $1$  to prove contractiveness, so my $18/25$ is good enough. One can find a smaller constant that works, which could be of interest if we want to talk about the *speed* of convergence.

Comment: got it thank you so much, i have more question can i ask you some more

Comment: Sure. Unless it is *very* closely connected to this problem, it is best to post a separate question. Probably best in any case. I cannot answer anything of any complexity in a comment. Too little space, and editing facilities are not good.

Comment: cool..thank you i will post one up about partial sums and find its sum